# craft\web\Request::cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key

Tags: error, env

For a while our Craft CMS webshop show errors in the control panel.
This happens 25%-50% of the requests. Looking in the phperror log a lot of this errors are logged:

[13-Dec-2021 23:00:05 UTC] An Error occurred while handling another error: yii\base\InvalidConfigException: craft\web\Request::cookieValidationKey must be configured with a secret key.

The SECURITY_KEY is set in the .env and also in /config/general.php

It seams like the server can't read or find the .env sometimes.
Earlier i found a topic to change the php variable 'variables_order' EGPCS.
This was not the solution for me.

Anyone some tips?

Craft CMS 3.7.24
PHP 7.4.26 
Hosted on Siteground